# Upgrading 4.6.4 to 4.7.7 on Wordpress Queue Runner error

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 4.7

I'm trying to upgrade CiviCRM 4.6.4 to 4.7.7 on Wordpress. Wordpress, MySQL, and PHP are all current. The update stalls and I get this error:

Exception: "Queue runner must be configured before execution."

I've cleared the cache, deleted and reinstalled several times, but always get this error. I can't find anything to explain it.